# Minecraft server daily restart script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I've been searching to try to find the information I need, but I have so far been unsuccessful.

What I would like to have happen daily is the following:

- Every time the machine starts, the Minecraft server is started. (I have the shell commands already written for this.)
- At 8:00 AM, the text "stop" is submitted to the server to cause it to gracefully stop.
- At 8:02 AM, the computer restarts.

Ideally, this will open a window on my desktop that enter commands into, and also have a way to send commands to the server through a remote terminal.

How do I do this? I have found information on using `sudo crontab -e` in order to allow super-user access needed to run the Minecraft server. I have also looked into using named pipes, but I can't quite get it working right. I can create it with `mkfifo mcserver`, but it blocks unless I open the pipe in another terminal. I have also looked into `screen`, as well as `echo`ing commands to a directory based on the pid, but I have not been able to get that to work either. How would I detect and store the pid?

Thank you for your help. It's greatly appreciated. I've been struggling with this for quite a while, and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  You want the MineCraft server box to restart, then to open a connection, allowing you to connect to it, and manage it, from a remote machine?

Comment: If you could help me migrate this to the correct forum, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: I would like to be able to manage it from a remote machine, yes. Most important is the daily graceful stop, reboot, and application start.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to reboot your computer every day?  Linux systems shouldn't need periodic rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

Use [this script](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Server_startup_script)

Then set your crontab for root up like this:

```
0 8 * * * service minecraft stop
2 8 * * * reboot
```

Then run

```
chkconfig minecraft on
```

to add the minecraft service to automatic start on boot.

Answer (score -2):

You *could* try using 'netcat'....

```
nc -l -p <port> -e /bin/bash
```

I can't say that this is in anyway secure; and I don't necessarily condone doing it.  Basically, this will literally BIND your BASH shell to a port of your choosing.  This is known as a "Reverse shell", and would most likely make your machine vulnerable; unless your firewall is configured properly. [iptables] Or some other method.

So you connect to your machine remotely, with netcat, by using:

```
nc <remote_ip> <port>
```

And it will provide an interface to send commands.

An alternative method would be to simply create a script that runs a listening VNC server, so you could connect remotely and manage it visually.  All of these options require care when connecting remotely and having opened ports [on a server].

I assume this is what you are asking.  Make a small BASH script and this is cake.  Or add it to your .rc files, and it will go automatically.